# Patching an ipa (iPhone app) using Hopper Disassembler

Tags: arm, ios, hopper

I have learned in the past to patch some iOS apps to bypass jailbreak detection. Today, I decided to change the UI elements in the Spotify app on iOS Platform (ios 11). I downloaded a .ipa file of Spotify and opened the executable using Hopper Disassembler v3. Can anyone experienced tell me which functions I should modify and resources that will help me identify other functions in the assembly code (64 bit)?

Comment: So your question is how to apply Hopper v3 to the task of patching you have done in the past, right?

Comment: Yes, since I cannot find any examples online other than the basic operations of creating NOP regions to bypass jailbreak detection